# How can I avoid capitalizing words in my sentence using Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

OK, so I have a problem with intermittently capitalizing a word in a sentence. My mind instinctively capitalize words that it considers important. But, when I read the sentence or paragraph later, It does not make sense to add those capitalizations, and it looks unprofessional. I can be using an Outlook or some text editor or a Word document, so it is not pertaining to a specific software.

While, I train my brain and unlearn some instinctive capitalizations, is there a way to modify Keyboard settings so that it does not capitalize even if I type (Shift + any alphabet)?

Is it possible to control these keyboard settings?

*Note:* I am using **Windows 10**. I am not looking for Word's auto-capitalize feature.

Thank you.

Comment: How will you type capital letters?

Comment: I was not completely thinking of disabling, but may be clicking shift key twice to enable "shift mode"

Comment: Perhaps look at the Ease Of Access features for the keyboard such as sticky keys of filter keys.

Answer (score 0):

There's a program called [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) that allows to you remap keys on Windows.

You could remap shift to some keycode that does nothing, or maybe even disable it completely.

The project README says that Microsoft's [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) provides some more functionality. It may be able to do exactly what you want. I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in word, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> will cycle highlighted text through different capitalization states.  If you need to explicitly block your shift key function, [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) is likely your best bet.

Comment: SHIFT + F3 in Word is a pretty cool trick. I was not aware of that. For my question, I will look into AHK. Thanks.